# Change soap1.1 to 1.2 (server) - Java EE

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

I have to update my soap11 Java EE webservice to a soap12 webservice. How should I do this? I've been googling and saw that it was just changing the namespace:

from:

```
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
```

to:

```
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
```

and that's it. But when I do that soapUI says it's SOAP 1.1 (even after refresh of the portBinding). So that can't be it.. What else should I do?

Webservice declaration:

```
@WebService(name = "testService", targetNamespace = "http://test.be/",
    wsdlLocation = "/META-INF/wsdl/testWSDL.wsdl",
    serviceName = "testService",
    portName = "testServicePort",
    endpointInterface = "test.testService")
@EndpointConfig(configFile = "WEB-INF/jaxws-endpoint-config.xml")
public class TestImpl implements Test {
```

Part of the wsdl:

```
<message name="test">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:test" />
</message>
<message name="testResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:testResponse" />
</message>
<message name="testError">
    <part name="fault" element="tns:testError" />
</message>
<portType name="testService">
    <operation name="test">
        <input
            wsam:Action="http://test.be/testService/testRequest"
            message="tns:test" />
        <output
            wsam:Action="http://test.be/testService/testResponse"
            message="tns:testResponse" />
        <fault message="tns:testError" name="testError" />
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="testServicePortBinding" type="tns:testService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
        style="document" />
    <operation name="addDocument">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" />
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
            <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#Wssp1.2-2007-Wss1.0-X509-Basic256.xml" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </output>
        <fault name="testError">
            <soap:fault name="testError" use="literal" />
        </fault>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="testService">
    <port name="testServicePort" binding="tns:testServicePortBinding">
        <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL" />
    </port>
</service>
```

Comment: What application server do you use? For example in weblogic the default is always 1.1: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webserv/soap12.html

Comment: `soap` prefix refer to what?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj jBoss 7.0

Comment: @Pasupathi xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"

Comment: In my SOAP 12 service, it is `xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"`

Comment: The http:// was removed by SO. It's the same with me.

Comment: Have yo defined `wsdl:portType` for tns:testService

Comment: @Pasupathi it has been added to the post.

Comment: Hope this link will help you http://wiki.aurionproject.org/display/AurionMain/Upgrade+soap+1.1+to+soap+1.2